# How to import or incorporate formated Excel tab into QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, printing, excel, print-composer

I would like to know if there's a way to import formated Excel Tab into QGIS print composer.

Below is an attachment of formatted Excel tab example I has been asked to display on qgis map composer.

Regards!

[image: formatted Excel tab example]

Comment: Which kind of formatting features do you need? Please provide a sample image mock-up.

Comment: Are you hoping to somehow have this live-linked to the Excel sheet? Or could you just capture a screenshot, save as image, and import the image into the print composer?

Answer (score 3):

As far as i can see you have 3 possibilities. Depending on the size and format of your excel table you might prefer one of the different solutions.

1. Open the table with your formating in Excel, make a screenshot and insert this screenshot as image in the QGIS print composer. You might also use other Image-Manipulation software (GIMP) to get better graphical results.
2. Export your excel table as comma-separated file (.csv using "," as delimiter) and add the table via the "Add Vector-Layer" button to QGIS. Now a simple table (not a layer) should appear in the QGIS-"table of contents". Then open the print-composer and manually add the imported table as attribute table to the composer. You can specify which columns you want to use and at least in the current development version of QGIS (QGIS 1.9 dev) you can also style the border and background of your attribute table (eg. add some custom colors). However the result won't look exactly like in excel.
3. You recreate the table directly in QGIS. Much easier if you know how to do it. First you need to reformat your whole excel table into HTML format. Search [google](http://tinyurl.com/co2uolu) how to do this. At least my libreoffice has an export-option to export a excel-table into html format. As soon as you have your table you simply add a new label via the QGIS composer and select the "Display as HTML"-Checkbox. Then copy paste your generated table into the label. You might need some skills in HTML/CSS formating though.

Comment: Thank all of you for your good answers. I'll give it a try. But actually I have clear idea on how I could handle this.Kind regards