# Inserting attribute table into QGIS Composer is limited to 99 rows

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

Inserting attribute table into QGIS Composer is limited to 99 rows?
Or am doing something wrong?

Stems from 
[How to import or incorporate formated Excel tab into QGIS print composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59132/how-to-import-or-incorporate-formated-excel-tab-into-qgis-print-composer?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the dimension size of the table was limiting the table, I dragged the bottom handle of the table down and the extra rows were exposed. Joy!